# Execute complex shell command from makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

I have the following command line that works from the Linux command prompt:

```
vi /tmp/test.txt -s <( echo ":1 s/^\/\/ VERSION: .*$/\/\/VERSION: $(date)/g" )
```

It creates a temporary file (using Process Substitution) that contains the following `vim` command:

```
:1 s/^\/\/ VERSION: .*$/\/\/ VERSION: $(date)/g
```

It opens file `/tmp/test.txt` for editing and executes the command from the previously created temporary file. It finds line 1 and replaces the line with a current time stamp. It looks a bit like this:

```
// VERSION: Fri Apr 12 21:20:03 CEST 2013
...
...
```

Next I can do any required editing and only when I decide to save the file, all changes are commited to disk. It is not an option to first change the file on disk, then start the editor, as the file will have a different timestamp while the contents itself didn't change.

So far it works as designed / intended.

Now I'm trying to move this vi command line into a make file and that is where I fail. I tried a `$(shell .....)` construction, but make is throwing errors at me.

```
edit:
        $(shell vi $(src).cpp -s <( echo ":1 s/^\/\/ VERSION: .*$/\/\/VERSION: $(date)/g" )
```

I'm trying to figure out how the line in the Makefile should read fiddling with extra quotes and parentheses, but I haven't solved it yet.

I am running Ubuntu Linux 12.10 and GNU Make 3.81

#### `vi project.cpp -s <( echo ":1 s/^\/\/ VERSION: .*$/\/\/VERSION: $(date)/g" )`

Make doesn't seem to like the "Process Substitution" construction `<( command )`. I do not want to use an extra (real) file.

```
€ make edit
vi project.cpp -s <( echo ":1 s/^\/\/ VERSION: .*$/\/\/VERSION: $(date)/g" )
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
make: *** [edit] Error 2
```

Comment: Please add the errors you get. What happens when you just put the command in the Makefile? `$(shell` should not be necessary.

Comment: Which command do you want, `:1 s/^\/\/ VERSION: .*$/\/\/VERSION: $(date)/g` or `:3,30 d|:1`?

Comment: @ExP added the information to the question

Comment: @Beta the very first one in my question is the correct one. For a brief moment I was in doubt for changing it to a simpler example, but I wanted to include the backslashes too as I expect problems there too.

Answer (score 12):

Using `$(shell ...)` inside of a make recipe is virtually never correct.  You're already in a shell... just type the commands you want directly.  Trying to use the make `$(shell ...)` function just adds confusion.  You will have to escape `$` by writing `$$`.

You have another problem: `make` always invokes its scripts using `/bin/sh` and you're using a bash-specific construct (`<(...)`).

Of course, the bigger question is why you're using vi, which is a visual editor, to do automated changes like this instead of, for example, `sed` which is designed for it.  I'd rewrite it as something like:

```
edit:
        sed -i "1 s,^// VERSION: .*,// VERSION: $$(date)," $(src).cpp
```

If you really want to use vi, you'll have to do something like:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

edit:
        vi '$(src).cpp' -s <( echo ":1 s/^\/\/ VERSION: .*$$/\/\/VERSION: $$(date)/g" )
```

Comment: I want to use `vi` because I want to manually edit the file from that point. I don't want to save a file with a changed timestamp if I'm not going to edit the rest of the file manually.

Comment: It's a bit strange to have a make target invoke an interactive command.  It can work, though, as long as you don't try to use `make -j`.  But you can't use bash constructs as I noted above.  You'll either have to use a real temporary file, or else add `SHELL := /bin/bash` to your makefile to force make to use bash rather than /bin/sh.

Comment: I know I am misusing make a bit. The idea is that I can do any required action to the source code just by typing `make edit` or `make flash`, `make fuses`, ... Your tip seems to work BTW. I see it is actually a shell issue :)